# Does this question seem to have formatting problems in Safari?

Tags: discussion, bug, formatting

A few minutes ago, a user reported in a moderator flag that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/97350/264) is not displaying correctly:

> The whole page (questions, answers, and comments) has formatting problems. Something weird is going on.

It looks fine to me, using Chrome 18.0.1025.168 m on Windows 7 64-bit, but I wanted to see if anyone is having the same problem with that question. I've also asked the person who made the flag to post here with OS and browser info, as well as screenshots of how the page looks to them.

Comment: Looks fine on Firefox 12.0 (OS: windows server 64 bit).

Comment: Looks fine on Chrome 19.0.1084.46 beta and Safari 5.1.2 on OS X 10.6.8.

Comment: Looks fine on my old cornputer.

Comment: It looks okay in Chrome 18.0.1025.142 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: I raised the same issue here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/math-processing-error-and-other-issues-with-mathjax) as well.

Comment: @Marvis, Your issue is slightly different in that the questions you cite are generating _[Math Processing Error]_ s and the ones I'm referencing do not (at least as far as I can tell).

Comment: @OldPro The *[Math Processing Error]* is in addition to the issue. I am too having a issue with the math rendering properly as you have shown in the post. I am on Safari MacOSX 10.7 as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here's how it looks to me:

[image]

Note the `\implies` in the question and `\Rightarrow` in the answer, and the extraneous underlining.

This is Safari 5.1.5 on on OS X 10.7.3 (current Safari on current Lion).

Comment: I raised the same issue here (http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4194/math-processing-error-and-other-issues-with-mathjax) as well.

Comment: The horizontal rules are an indication that MathJax has crashed during its process of measuring the font sizes and column widths.  Are there "[Math Processing Error]" message further down the page?  Does the problem continue to occur if you reload the page?  Is the first processing error always at the same location?  If so, where? (PS, Safari 5.1.7 and Lion 10.7.4 were recently released.)

Comment: @Davide, yes, Safari 5.1.7 was released the day after this question and this answer were posted.  No change in behavior relating to the problem post.  There are no "[Math Processing Error]" messages on the page.  Sometimes reloading fixes the problem and sometimes it does not.  The only console error I get is one that complains about a quantserve resource "interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/plain."

Comment: @OldPro, thanks for the data.  Could you try the following?  Enter `javascript:alert(MathJax.Message.Log())` on a page that shows the problem, and if there is a message about a preprocess error, enter `javascript:alert(MathJax.Hub.lastPrepError.message)` and let me know what these two results are?  Thanks.

Comment: Loading [MathJax]/config/TeX-AMS_HTML.js
Loading [MathJax]/extensions/TeX/mathchoice.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/jax.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX/fontdata.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX/fontdata-1.0.js
***Error preparing HTML-CSS output (preProcess)***
Loading [MathJax]/jax/element/mml/optable/SuppMathOperators.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX/General/Regular/SuppMathOperators.js
Loading [MathJax]/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/STIX/General/Regular/LetterlikeSymbols.js

Comment: `'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'k.root')`

Answer (score 3):

I tried on my computer and got a mess first time, which cleared when I used the refresh button. I am currently using Safari 5.1.7 with Lion (OSX 10.7.4) on a Mac.

I get intermittent failures of this kind, but have never yet met a situation where refreshing the screen did not work.

Comment: I'm seeing a failure that won't go away with this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m

Comment: Or rather, I cannot simultaneously view http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/152671/some-elementary-number-theory-proofs and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3118/if-a-m-and-a-1-m-prove-aa-1-m as it seems they have something different (e.g. maybe different versions of TeX-AMS_HTML.js) that somehow look the same to Safari's cache.

Comment: What is interesting about all these questions is that I get the problem consistently with all of them, but they all go away when I refresh, and - on my system - I can get them up and OK together.

Comment: That is crazy. If I have both of those tabs open, one of them fails, even after reloads (horizontal rules, no fonts, mostly blank where the math should be, no "math processing errors").  Once I close one of the tabs, a reload fixes the other.